# From when to when/what time to what time?

Tags: phrase-usage, alternatives

Is 'from when to when?' or 'from what time to what time?' proper/natural English? Would their usage come up in a conversation between native speakers as a super concise way of asking when something starts and when it will end?  For example:

A: I will be going away on a holiday to Paris.

B: Oh that's nice. From when to when?

If it's not idiomatic, how else I can express the same query without being too wordy? What are some alternative phrases, both formal and informal?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of stating _when to when_, just say "Oh, that's nice. When?" or "Oh, that's nice. For how long?" Your response will generally be provided in that format ("from the 3rd to the 7th of June").

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Oh that's nice. From when to when?

There's nothing really wrong with this, but *when* doesn't necessarily resolve to a specific date.  Valid answers to "when" include "January 3rd," "tomorrow," "sometime next week," "whenever Bobby gets here," etc.

If you want a date range, be explicit - and probably the least wordy way to do that is:

> Oh that's nice.  What dates?

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing wrong with "from when to when?"

Since you are asking two questions, and as this is a conversation, speakers may choose to break it up. "When are you going?" "Next Monday", "So, when will you be back?" and so on. It's longer but that's okay in a conversation.

Answer (score 2):

While "when to when" is correct -- it comes across as a little pushy when asking casually about someone's holiday.

For inquiring casually about someone's holiday you can use:
 - Oh that's nice.  When are you going?  (You can follow with another question.  "How long are you going for?")

For asking about dates in order to set an appointment or specific timing:

- Yes, I can walk your dog while you're away.  Which dates will you be gone?

Answer (score 1):

Both "**from when to when**" and "**from what time to what time**" are natural to me as a non-native speaker.

- **from when to when** - carries the meanings of '*when are you leaving and when will you be back*' and '*when will it start and will it end*'. It asks for a start date and an end date. One could answer to this using "*to*", "*till*", "*until*" or "*through*".
- **from what time to what time** - mostly covers time intervals. As an answer one could say, "*from 9am to 2pm*" or "*from 5pm till 7pm*".

As a more concise way of saying it I would suggest "**What dates?**" *(speaking about dates)* or "**When?**" *(speaking about periods and can also address a precise day, month, year or even season)*